# In which Stack Exchange site would it be on topic to ask questions about Windows 8?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a specific question regarding the task manager of Windows 8.1. Where can I ask my question?

Comment: What is your "specific" question, as there are various sites a "Windows" question could potentially be ok on. Try looking here:  http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology

Comment: The question is about disk usage monitoring and the use of C-cleaner and Avast. Super user seems to work fine, my question has been answered

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can go to [Super User](http://superuser.com). Their [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) describes that questions about computer software are on-topic.